# Javascript Array concat function

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

case1

```
let history = [{temp : 123}];
history.concat({temp:1234}); //[{temp :123}, {temp:1234}]
```

case2

```
let history = [{temp : 123}];
history.concat([{temp:1234}]): //[{temp :123}, {temp:1234}]
```

case3

```
let history = [{temp : 123}];
history.concat([[{temp:1234}]]); //[{temp :123}, [{temp:1234}]]
```

why concat method returns same output in case1 and case2?

According to me case1 and case3 is expected, but case2 is unexpected.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 2):

case1: `array.concat(nonArray)` -> add the nonArray to the array

case2: `array.concat(newArray)` -> add every element of newArray to the array

case3: `array.concat(twoDArray)` -> add every element of twoDArray to the array, but every element of the twoDArray IS ITSELF an array.

case2 actually behaves exactly the same as case3

Comment: Case **1** behaves exactly the same as case 2. *edit* unless you mean that the same basic operation is performed, which is certainly true. With the actual data from the OP, the *results* are the same between 1 and 2.

Comment: Wrong. Case 2 and Case 3 have the same type of argument, which is an array. Case 1 is the odd one out, because you're passing an object rather than an array

Comment: Yes but the wording is confusing because it echos what's in the OP, and the results are what the OP was confused about.

Comment: I'm explaining what's happening in case 2 and case 3, and why they're doing the exact same thing as each other. When you pass an array to `concat`, it adds every element of that array. Case 3 adds a 2d array, so you're adding arrays to the array, rather than objects.

Comment: Sure, I understand what's going on and you're right of course.